# Find out variable/function scope with ANTLR 4 ParseTreeListener and R grammar

Tags: java, r, scope, listener, antlr

I am wondering about how to determine the scope of a variable or function using the **ParseTreeListener** and a custom listener "MyRListener" which extends the **RBaseListener**. My idea is to create a list of all variables and functions in a code file and to keep the structure, what means that I want to add subfunctions or variables as children of the corresponding function (so I keep a kind of hierarchy).

In other words I need to know when a function is exited. In some other ANTLR4 grammers there a Listener events for exiting a function, but unfortunately not in the R grammar (https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/r).

I've already tried to use the **invokingState** as indicator if a function is exited, but it does not seem to work for all kind of R scripts, because it already failed..

**MyRListener.java**:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Stack;

import model.code.antlr4.generated.RBaseListener;
import model.code.antlr4.generated.RParser;
import model.code.elements.FunctionElement;

public class MyRListener extends RBaseListener {

    static class FunctionPair {
        private FunctionElement functionElement;
        private int invokingState;

        public FunctionPair(FunctionElement functionElement, int invokingState) {
            this.functionElement = functionElement;
            this.invokingState = invokingState;
        }

        public FunctionElement getFunctionElement() {
            return functionElement;
        }

        public int getInvokingState() {
            return invokingState;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "FunctionPair [functionElement=" + functionElement + ", invokingState=" + invokingState + "]";
        }
    }

    // https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#What-are-valid-names_003f
    private final String pattern_valid_name = "[a-zA-Z0-9._]*";
    // https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Reserved.html
    private final Set<String> reserved_words = new HashSet<String>(
            Arrays.asList(new String[] { "if", "else", "repeat", "while", "function", "for", "in", "next", "break" }));

    private Stack<FunctionPair> functionStack;

    public MyRListener() {
        this.functionStack = new Stack<FunctionPair>();
    }

    public void enterExpr(RParser.ExprContext ctx) {
        String txt = ctx.getText().trim();

        if (!(ctx.getChildCount() > 2))
            return;

        String name = ctx.getChild(0).getText().replace("\"", "");
        String operator = ctx.getChild(1).getText().trim();

        if (!reserved_words.contains(name) && name.matches(pattern_valid_name)
                && (txt.contains("<-function") || txt.contains("=function"))) {
            System.out.println("Function:" + name);

            FunctionElement parent = functionStack.isEmpty() ? null : functionStack.peek().functionElement;

            FunctionElement func = new FunctionElement(name, parent);
            FunctionPair fpair = new FunctionPair(func, ctx.invokingState);


            if (!functionStack.isEmpty())
            functionStack.peek().functionElement.addSubFunction(func);

            functionStack.push(fpair);
        } else if (!reserved_words.contains(name) && name.matches(pattern_valid_name) && txt.contains("<-")) {
            if (operator.equals("=") || operator.equals("<-"))
                System.out.println("Variable:" + name);
        } else {

        }
    }

    public void exitExpr(RParser.ExprContext ctx) {
        if (functionStack.peek().getInvokingState() == ctx.invokingState) {
            System.out.println("__Function " + functionStack.peek().getFunctionElement() + " ends here!");
            System.out.print("__Children: ");
            functionStack.peek().getFunctionElement().printChildren();
            // cm is a list which is not in the minimal example for stackoverflow
            this.cm.addCodeElement(functionStack.pop().functionElement);
        }

    }

    public void enterForm(RParser.FormContext ctx) {
        String name = ctx.getChild(0).getText().replace("\"", "");
        //System.out.println("Parameter: " + name);
    }

}
```

**R.g4**:

```
grammar R;

prog:   (   expr (';'|NL)
        |   NL
        )*
        EOF
    ;

/*
expr_or_assign
    :   expr ('<-'|'='|'<<-') expr_or_assign
    |   expr
    ;
*/

expr:   expr '[[' sublist ']' ']'  // '[[' follows R's yacc grammar
    |   expr '[' sublist ']'
    |   expr ('::'|':::') expr
    |   expr ('$'|'@') expr
    |   <assoc=right> expr '^' expr
    |   ('-'|'+') expr
    |   expr ':' expr
    |   expr USER_OP expr // anything wrappedin %: '%' .* '%'
    |   expr ('*'|'/') expr
    |   expr ('+'|'-') expr
    |   expr ('>'|'>='|'<'|'<='|'=='|'!=') expr
    |   '!' expr
    |   expr ('&'|'&&') expr
    |   expr ('|'|'||') expr
    |   '~' expr
    |   expr '~' expr
    |   expr ('<-'|'<<-'|'='|'->'|'->>'|':=') expr
    |   'function' '(' formlist? ')' expr // define function
    |   expr '(' sublist ')'              // call function
    |   '{' exprlist '}' // compound statement
    |   'if' '(' expr ')' expr
    |   'if' '(' expr ')' expr 'else' expr
    |   'for' '(' ID 'in' expr ')' expr
    |   'while' '(' expr ')' expr
    |   'repeat' expr
    |   '?' expr // get help on expr, usually string or ID
    |   'next'
    |   'break'
    |   '(' expr ')'
    |   ID
    |   STRING
    |   HEX
    |   INT
    |   FLOAT
    |   COMPLEX
    |   'NULL'
    |   'NA'
    |   'Inf'
    |   'NaN'
    |   'TRUE'
    |   'FALSE'
    ;

exprlist
    :   expr ((';'|NL) expr?)*
    |
    ;

formlist : form (',' form)* ;

form:   ID
    |   ID '=' expr
    |   '...'
    ;

sublist : sub (',' sub)* ;

sub :   expr
    |   ID '='
    |   ID '=' expr
    |   STRING '='
    |   STRING '=' expr
    |   'NULL' '='
    |   'NULL' '=' expr
    |   '...'
    |
    ;

HEX :   '0' ('x'|'X') HEXDIGIT+ [Ll]? ;

INT :   DIGIT+ [Ll]? ;

fragment
HEXDIGIT : ('0'..'9'|'a'..'f'|'A'..'F') ;

FLOAT:  DIGIT+ '.' DIGIT* EXP? [Ll]?
    |   DIGIT+ EXP? [Ll]?
    |   '.' DIGIT+ EXP? [Ll]?
    ;
fragment
DIGIT:  '0'..'9' ; 
fragment
EXP :   ('E' | 'e') ('+' | '-')? INT ;

COMPLEX
    :   INT 'i'
    |   FLOAT 'i'
    ;

STRING
    :   '"' ( ESC | ~[\\"] )*? '"'
    |   '\'' ( ESC | ~[\\'] )*? '\''
    |   '`' ( ESC | ~[\\'] )*? '`'
    ;

fragment
ESC :   '\\' [abtnfrv"'\\]
    |   UNICODE_ESCAPE
    |   HEX_ESCAPE
    |   OCTAL_ESCAPE
    ;

fragment
UNICODE_ESCAPE
    :   '\\' 'u' HEXDIGIT HEXDIGIT HEXDIGIT HEXDIGIT
    |   '\\' 'u' '{' HEXDIGIT HEXDIGIT HEXDIGIT HEXDIGIT '}'
    ;

fragment
OCTAL_ESCAPE
    :   '\\' [0-3] [0-7] [0-7]
    |   '\\' [0-7] [0-7]
    |   '\\' [0-7]
    ;

fragment
HEX_ESCAPE
    :   '\\' HEXDIGIT HEXDIGIT?
    ;

ID  :   '.' (LETTER|'_'|'.') (LETTER|DIGIT|'_'|'.')*
    |   LETTER (LETTER|DIGIT|'_'|'.')*
    ;

fragment LETTER  : [a-zA-Z] ;

USER_OP :   '%' .*? '%' ;

COMMENT :   '#' .*? '\r'? '\n' -> type(NL) ;

// Match both UNIX and Windows newlines
NL      :   '\r'? '\n' ;

WS      :   [ \t\u000C]+ -> skip ;
```

**Code to run the ParseTreeListener**:

```
ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(fileInputStream);
Lexer lexer = new RLexer(input);
CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
RFilter filter = new RFilter(tokens);
filter.stream();
tokens.reset();
Parser parser = new RParser(tokens);
ParseTree tree = ((RParser) parser).prog();
ParserTreeListener listener = new MyRListener(codeModel);
```

**Input (chron.R)**

```
"chron" <-
function(dates. = NULL, times. = NULL,
         format = c(dates = "m/d/y", times = "h:m:s"),
         out.format, origin.)
{
    if(is.null(format))
        format <- c(dates = "m/d/y", times = "h:m:s")
    if(missing(out.format)){
        if(is.character(format))
            out.format <- format
        else
            stop('must specify the "out.format" argument')
    }
    given <- c(dates = !missing(dates.), times = !missing(times.))
    if(is.null(default.origin <- getOption("chron.origin")))
        default.origin <- c(month = 1, day = 1, year = 1970)
    if(all(!given))
        ## dates and times missing
        return(structure(numeric(0),
                         format = format, origin = default.origin,
                         class = c("chron", "dates", "times")))
    if(inherits(dates., "dates")) {
        if(missing(origin.))
            origin. <- origin(dates.)
        else origin(dates.) <- origin.
    }
    else if(missing(origin.))
        origin. <- default.origin
    if(given["dates"] && !given["times"]) {
        ## presumably only dates
        if(missing(format) && inherits(dates., "dates"))
            format <- attr(dates., "format")
        fmt <- switch(mode(format),
                      character = ,
                      list = format[[1]],
                      name = ,
                      "function" = format,
                      NULL = c(dates = "m/d/y"),
                      stop("unrecognized format"))
        dts <- convert.dates(dates., format = fmt, origin. = origin.)
        tms <- dts - floor(dts) 
    ## if dates include fractions of days create a full chron
        if(!all(is.na(tms)) && any(tms[!is.na(tms)] != 0))
            return(chron(dates. = floor(dts), times. = tms, format
                         = format, out.format = out.format, origin. = 
                         origin.))
        ofmt <- switch(mode(out.format),
                       character = ,
                       list = out.format[[1]],
                       name = ,
                       "function" = out.format,
                       NULL = c(dates = "m/d/y"),
                       stop("invalid output format"))
        attr(dts, "format") <- ofmt
        attr(dts, "origin") <- origin.
        class(dts) <- c("dates", "times")
        names(dts) <- names(dates.)
        return(dts)
    }
    if(given["times"] && !given["dates"]) {
        ## only times
        if(missing(format) && inherits(times., "times")) {
            format <- attr(times., "format")
            if(!is.name(format))
                format <- rev(format)[[1]]
        }
        fmt <- switch(mode(format),
                      character = ,
                      list = rev(format)[[1]],
                      name = ,
                      "function" = format,
                      NULL = c(times = "h:m:s"),
                      stop("invalid times input format"))
        tms <- convert.times(times., fmt)
        ofmt <- switch(mode(out.format),
                       character = ,
                       list = rev(out.format)[[1]],
                       name = ,
                       "function" = out.format,
                       NULL = c(dates = "m/d/y"),
                       stop("invalid times output format"))
        attr(tms, "format") <- ofmt
        class(tms) <- "times"
        names(tms) <- names(times.)
        return(tms)
    }
    ## both dates and times 
    if(length(times.) != length(dates.)) {
        if(length(times.) == 1)
            times. <- rep.int(times., length(dates.))
        else if(length(dates.) == 1)
            dates. <- rep.int(dates., length(times.))
        else
            stop(paste(deparse(substitute(dates.)), "and",
                       deparse(substitute(times.)), "must have equal lengths"))
    }
    if(missing(format)) {
        if(is.null(fmt.d <- attr(dates., "format")))
            fmt.d <- format[1]
        if(is.null(fmt.t <- attr(times., "format")))
            fmt.t <- format[2]
        if(mode(fmt.d) == "character" && mode(fmt.t) == "character")
            format <- structure(c(fmt.d, fmt.t),
                                names = c("dates", "times"))
        else {
            fmt.d <- if(is.name(fmt.d)) fmt.d else fmt.d[[1]]
            fmt.t <- if(is.name(fmt.t)) fmt.t else rev(fmt.t)[[1]]
            format <- list(dates = fmt.d, times = fmt.t)
        }
    }
    if(any(length(format) != 2, length(out.format) != 2))
        stop("misspecified chron format(s) length")
    if(all(mode(format) != c("character", "list")))
        stop("misspecified input format(s)")
    if(all(mode(out.format) != c("list", "character")))
        stop("misspecified output format(s)")
    dts <- convert.dates(dates., format = format[[1]], origin. = origin.)
    tms <- convert.times(times., format = format[[2]])
    x <- unclass(dts) + unclass(tms)
    attr(x, "format") <- out.format
    attr(x, "origin") <- origin.
    class(x) <- c("chron", "dates", "times")
    nms <- paste(names(dates.), names(times.))
    if(length(nms) && any(nms != ""))
        names(x) <- nms
    return(x)
}

as.chron <- function(x, ...) UseMethod("as.chron")
as.chron.default <- function (x, format, ...)
{
    if(inherits(x, "chron"))
        return(x)
    if(is.numeric(x)) {
        if (missing(format) || is.null(format)) return(chron(x, ...))
        else return(as.chron(as.POSIXct(format(x, scientific = FALSE),
                                        tz = "GMT", format = format),
                             ...))
    }
    if (is.character(x)) {
        if (missing(format) || is.null(format)) {
            out <- suppressWarnings(try(chron(x, ...), silent = TRUE))
            ## If this fails, try Date or datetime.
            if(inherits(out, "try-error")) {
                xx <- sub("T", " ", x)
                out <- if(!any(grepl(" ", x, fixed = TRUE)))
                    as.chron(as.Date(xx), ...)
                else
                    as.chron(as.POSIXct(xx, tz = "GMT"), ...)
            }
        } else {
            out <- as.chron(as.POSIXct(x, format = format, tz = "GMT"),
                            ...)
        }
        return(out)
    }
    stop("'x' cannot be coerced to a chron object")
}
as.chron.POSIXt <- function(x, offset = 0, tz = "GMT", ...)
{
    ## offset is in hours relative to GMT
    if(!inherits(x, "POSIXt")) stop("wrong method")
    x <- as.numeric(as.POSIXct(as.character(x, tz = tz), tz = "GMT")) +
        60 * round(60 * offset)
    tm <- x %% 86400
    # if(any(tm != 0))
        chron(dates. = x %/% 86400, times. = tm / 86400, ...)
    # else
    #   chron(dates. = x %/% 86400, ...)
}
as.chron.Date <- function(x, ...)
{
    chron(unclass(x), ...)
}

asChronYearFreq <-
function(x, frac = 0, holidays = FALSE, frequency, ...)
{
    stopifnot(isTRUE((12 / frequency) %% 1 == 0))
    x <- unclass(x)
    year <- floor(x + 0.001)
    month <- floor(12 * (x - year) + 1 + 0.5 + 0.001)
    dd.start <- as.Date(paste(year, month, 1, sep = "-"))
    nd <- 32 * 12 / frequency 
    dd.end <- dd.start + nd - as.numeric(format(dd.start + nd, "%d"))
    if(identical(holidays, FALSE))
        chron(((1 - frac) * as.numeric(dd.start) +
               frac * as.numeric(dd.end)),
              ...)
    else
        chron(sapply(seq_along(x), function(i) {
            s <- unclass(seq(dd.start[i], dd.end[i], by = "days"))
            h <- if(isTRUE(holidays)) is.holiday(s) else is.holiday(s, holidays)
            ss <- s[!is.weekend(s) & !h]
            quantile(ss, probs = frac, names = FALSE)
        }), ...)
}

as.chron.yearmon <-
function(x, frac = 0, holidays = FALSE, ...)
{
    asChronYearFreq(x, frac = frac, holidays = holidays,
                    frequency = 12, ...)
}

as.chron.yearqtr <-
function(x, frac = 0, holidays = FALSE, ...)
{
    asChronYearFreq(x, frac = frac, holidays = holidays,
                    frequency = 4, ...)
}

as.chron.ts <-
function(x, frac = 0, holidays = FALSE, ...)
{
    asChronYearFreq(time(x), frac = frac, holidays = holidays,
                    frequency = frequency(x), ...)
}

as.chron.factor <- function(x, ...) 
{
    as.chron(as.character(x), ...)
}

"is.chron" <-
function(x)
    inherits(x, "chron")

as.data.frame.chron <- as.data.frame.vector

"convert.chron" <-
function(x, format = c(dates = "m/d/y", times = "h:m:s"), origin.,
         sep = " ", enclose = c("(", ")"), ...)
{
    if(is.null(x) || !as.logical(length(x)))
        return(numeric(length = 0))
    if(is.numeric(x))
        return(x)
    if(!is.character(x) && all(!is.na(x)))
        stop(paste("objects", deparse(substitute(x)), 
                   "must be numeric or character"))
    if(length(format) != 2)
        stop("format must have length==2")
    if(missing(origin.)
       && is.null(origin. <- getOption("chron.origin")))
        origin. <- c(month = 1, day = 1, year = 1970)
    if(any(enclose != ""))
        x <- substring(x, first = 2, last = nchar(x) - 1)
    str <- unpaste(x, sep = sep)
    dts <- convert.dates(str[[1]], format = format[[1]],
                         origin. = origin., ...)
    tms <- convert.times(str[[2]], format = format[[2]], ...)
    dts + tms
}

"format.chron" <-
function(x, format = att$format, origin. = att$origin, sep = " ",
         simplify, enclosed = c("(", ")"), ...)
{
    att <- attributes(x)
    if(length(format) == 1L) {
        if(!nzchar(format))
            format <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
        return(format(as.POSIXct(x), format = format, tz = "GMT"))
    }
    if(missing(simplify))
        if(is.null(simplify <- getOption("chron.simplify")))
            simplify <- FALSE
    dts <- format.dates(x, format[[1]], origin. = origin., simplify = 
                        simplify)
    tms <- format.times(x - floor(x), format[[2]], simplify = simplify)
    x <- paste(enclosed[1], dts, sep, tms, enclosed[2], sep = "")   
    ## output is a character object w.o class
    att$class <- att$format <- att$origin <- NULL
    attributes(x) <- att
    x
}

"new.chron" <-
function(x, new.origin = c(1, 1, 1970),
         shift = julian(new.origin[1], new.origin[2], new.origin[3],
         c(0, 0, 0)))
{
    cl <- class(x)
    class(x) <- NULL                    # get rid of "delim" attribute
    del <- attr(x, "delim")
    attr(x, "delim") <- NULL            # map formats
    format <- attr(x, "format")
    format[1] <- switch(format[1],
                        abb.usa = paste("m", "d", "y", sep = del[1]),
                        abb.world = paste("d", "m", "y", sep = del[1]),
                        abb.ansi = "ymd",
                        full.usa = "month day year",
                        full.world = "day month year",
                        full.ansi = "year month year",
                        format[1])
    if(length(format) == 2)
        format[2] <- switch(format[2],
                            military = "h:m:s",
                            format[2])
    attr(x, "format") <- format
    orig <- attr(x, "origin")
    if(is.null(orig)) {
        x <- x - shift
        attr(x, "origin") <- new.origin
    }
    ## (update origin after we assign the proper class!)
    ## deal with times as attributes 
    tms <- attr(x, "times")
    if(!is.null(tms)) {
        if(all(tms[!is.na(tms)] >= 1))
            tms <- tms/(24 * 3600)
        x <- x + tms
        class(x) <- c("chron", "dates", "times")
    }
    else class(x) <- c("dates", "times")
    x
}

print.chron <-
function(x, digits = NULL, quote = FALSE, prefix = "", sep = " ",
         enclosed = c("(", ")"), simplify, ...)
{
    if(!as.logical(length(x))) {
        cat("chron(0)\n")
        return(invisible(x))
    }
    if(missing(simplify) &&
       is.null(simplify <- getOption("chron.simplify")))
            simplify <- FALSE
    xo <- x
    x <- format.chron(x, sep = sep, enclosed = enclosed, simplify = 
                      simplify)
    print.default(x, quote = quote)
    invisible(xo)
}

unique.chron <-
function(x, incomparables = FALSE, ...) 
    x[!duplicated(x, incomparables, ...)]

xtfrm.chron <-
function(x)
    as.numeric(x)

pretty.chron <-
function(x, ...)
{
   if(!inherits(x, "times"))
       x <- chron(x)
   x <- as.POSIXct(x)
   attr(x, "tzone") <- "GMT"
   ans <- pretty(x, ...)
   structure(as.chron(ans), labels = attr(ans, "labels"))
}
```

**Error output from ANTLR:**

```
line 11:12 no viable alternative at input 'if(missing(out.format)){\nif(is.character(format))\nout.format<-format\nelse\n'
line 8:27 missing {';', NL} at '{'
line 11:12 extraneous input '\n' expecting {'-', '+', '!', '~', 'function', '(', '{', 'if', 'for', 'while', 'repeat', '?', 'next', 'break', 'NULL', 'NA', 'Inf', 'NaN', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', HEX, INT, FLOAT, COMPLEX, STRING, ID}
line 93:12 no viable alternative at input 'if(length(times.)!=length(dates.)){\nif(length(times.)==1)\ntimes.<-rep.int(times.,length(dates.))\nelseif(length(dates.)==1)\ndates.<-rep.int(dates.,length(times.))\nelse\n'
line 96:4 extraneous input '}' expecting {<EOF>, '-', '+', '!', '~', 'function', '(', '{', 'if', 'for', 'while', 'repeat', '?', 'next', 'break', 'NULL', 'NA', 'Inf', 'NaN', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', HEX, INT, FLOAT, COMPLEX, STRING, ID, NL}
line 127:0 extraneous input '}' expecting {<EOF>, '-', '+', '!', '~', 'function', '(', '{', 'if', 'for', 'while', 'repeat', '?', 'next', 'break', 'NULL', 'NA', 'Inf', 'NaN', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', HEX, INT, FLOAT, COMPLEX, STRING, ID, NL}
line 148:20 no viable alternative at input 'if(is.character(x)){\nif(missing(format)||is.null(format)){\nout<-suppressWarnings(try(chron(x,...),silent=TRUE))\n## If this fails, try Date or datetime.\nif(inherits(out,"try-error")){\nxx<-sub("T"," ",x)\nout<-if(!any(grepl(" ",x,fixed=TRUE)))\nas.chron(as.Date(xx),...)\nelse\n'
line 140:25 missing {';', NL} at '{'
line 148:20 no viable alternative at input 'if(missing(format)||is.null(format)){\nout<-suppressWarnings(try(chron(x,...),silent=TRUE))\n## If this fails, try Date or datetime.\nif(inherits(out,"try-error")){\nxx<-sub("T"," ",x)\nout<-if(!any(grepl(" ",x,fixed=TRUE)))\nas.chron(as.Date(xx),...)\nelse\n'
line 148:20 no viable alternative at input 'if(inherits(out,"try-error")){\nxx<-sub("T"," ",x)\nout<-if(!any(grepl(" ",x,fixed=TRUE)))\nas.chron(as.Date(xx),...)\nelse\n'
line 148:20 extraneous input '\n' expecting {'-', '+', '!', '~', 'function', '(', '{', 'if', 'for', 'while', 'repeat', '?', 'next', 'break', 'NULL', 'NA', 'Inf', 'NaN', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', HEX, INT, FLOAT, COMPLEX, STRING, ID}
line 151:8 extraneous input '}' expecting {<EOF>, '-', '+', '!', '~', 'function', '(', '{', 'if', 'for', 'while', 'repeat', '?', 'next', 'break', 'NULL', 'NA', 'Inf', 'NaN', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', HEX, INT, FLOAT, COMPLEX, STRING, ID, NL}
line 156:4 extraneous input '}' expecting {<EOF>, '-', '+', '!', '~', 'function', '(', '{', 'if', 'for', 'while', 'repeat', '?', 'next', 'break', 'NULL', 'NA', 'Inf', 'NaN', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', HEX, INT, FLOAT, COMPLEX, STRING, ID, NL}
line 158:0 extraneous input '}' expecting {<EOF>, '-', '+', '!', '~', 'function', '(', '{', 'if', 'for', 'while', 'repeat', '?', 'next', 'break', 'NULL', 'NA', 'Inf', 'NaN', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', HEX, INT, FLOAT, COMPLEX, STRING, ID, NL}
line 190:8 extraneous input '\n' expecting {'-', '+', '!', '~', 'function', '(', '{', 'if', 'for', 'while', 'repeat', '?', 'next', 'break', 'NULL', 'NA', 'Inf', 'NaN', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', HEX, INT, FLOAT, COMPLEX, STRING, ID}
```

Comment: I guess you are expecting us to run this Java program.  You might get more contributions of ideas if you posted whatever errors you are seeing with whatever  'input' you are testing with. (Not all R users are also Java users.)

Comment: Thanks, I added an example input file at my original post. I dont really get errors, I just dont know which ANTLR concept helps me when I want to keep track of the function/variable scope.

Comment: That's quite a bit of input. I don't really think it qualifies as an [MCVE]. And I don't think you have described the problem you see with how it runs. You say no errors, so why are you asking the question?

Comment: Thanks again, I also added error/warning output from ANTLR.